# Processing mapping always out of bounds

Tags: java, maps, processing

I'm trying to make a graph in processing, but keep getting the "ArrayIndexOutOfBounds" error. I am having a hard time understanding the concept of the map() syntax, could anyone clear it up for me? I'm not sure what every number is supposed to stand for within map(x,y,z,a,b);

```
String[] name = {
  "1st:",
  "5th:",
  "10th:",
  "15th:",
  "20th:",
  "25th:",
  "30th:"
};

int[] temperature = {
  81,
  82,
  84,
  85,
  87,
  88,
  90
};


void setup(){
  size(200,200);
}

void draw(){
  int x=0;
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

    if(mouseX>x && mouseX<=x+40){
      fill(255,40,40);
    }else{
      fill(50);
    }

    float h = map(temperature[i], 0, 100, 0, 200);

    rect(x+4,height-h,32,h);

    x+=40;
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you post the stack trace of the exception you are getting?

Comment: To what class does the map() method belong?

Comment: You have not shown us your map()-method or a documentation of it so we cannot guess, but the reason for your `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is very clear, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arrays have 7 elements, but you iterate 10 times.

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
  ...
  float h = map(temperature[i], 0, 100, 0, 200);

}
```

Either you fill up your arrays with additional 3 elements, or better: Instead of the number 10 you should use `i < temperature.length()` as condition in for-loop.